# android: receiver not receiving any broadcast when bluetooth device disconnected

Tags: android, bluetooth

I created a receiver, when my headset connected to my test device, i was able to receive the android.bluetooth.device.action.ACL_CONNECTED, but when i manually disconnect or power off the headset, it didn't broadcast anything. I was expecting to receive "android.bluetooth.device.action.ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECTED".

i have these intent filter for my receiver declared:

```
            <action android:name="android.bluetooth.adapter.action.DISCOVERY_FINISHED" />
            <action android:name="android.bluetooth.device.action.ACL_CONNECTED" />
            <action android:name="android.bluetooth.device.action.ACTION_FOUND" />
            <action android:name="android.bluetooth.device.action.ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECT_REQUESTED" />
            <action android:name="android.bluetooth.device.action.ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECTED" />
```

additional info : my test device is running android 6 .

Any idea why? Or something that i missed out?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a typo, action should be (no ACTION_ in the string):

```
<action android:name="android.bluetooth.device.action.ACL_DISCONNECTED" />
```

Comment: oh my! been physically connect/disconnect my headset to troubleshoot this. Thanks for pointing them out. working fine .